# Fetching nth document based on integer array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

so let's say I have a random array of n integers [23, 2, 78, 99, ... ] where  0 < n < collection.count(), and each element is within this range as well.

In my collection, it is currently indexed by _id, and say it contains the following data:

```
{
    "_id" : "1293jnqke",
    "name" : "name_string",
    "other_data" : [{
        "data" : ...
    }]
}
```

How should I go about grabbing the data, in chunks of 50, which correspond to each element in the array? So with the example integer array I have, I will slice it down to the first 50 elements, and then I wish to run a find() on the collection, extracting the names of the 23rd, 2nd, 78th, 99th, etc elements, based on the natural ordering of the collection (no need for any sorting beforehand). So the output should look like this:

```
{
    [ {"name" : "23rd name"},
    {"name" : "2nd name"},
    {"name" : "78th name"},
    {"name" : "99th name"},
    {"name" : "53rd name"},
    {"name" : "11th name"},
    ...]
}
```

One way of course is by looping through the array with findOne() and skip() but I don't think that is very efficient, is it possible to execute this in a single query? Or are there any better methods?

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: I noticed this question was also posted & discussed on the MongoDB Developer Community Forums: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/fetching-nth-document-based-on-integer-array/13547/2

Comment: @Stennie - Yes I asked the question in both communities to see if there would be any differing methods of doing this. It's been answered in the Mongo community forums. There may be another method using cursors, but I've not worked out the intricacies of that yet.